# How can I implement and activate search in a Windows 8 app?

Tags: javascript, search, windows-8

I want to allow my app to use the Windows 8 search charm and despite going through the extensive search documentation on MSDN I seem to be missing the first step. Firstly, I have already declared that I wish to use search in the Project Manifest, and I have added the code in my header to link my `default.html`with the `searchResults.js file`.

The documentation then suggests that using system search should just 'work'. How this does not happen for me, when I do a search it does not open my app on the default, blank search results page. I have tried adding the following to my `default.js` page, but to no avail:

```
  // When the user submits a search query
Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onquerysubmitted =
    // Call the function 
    function (eventObject) {

        winJS.log && WinJS.log("User submitted the search query: " + eventObject.queryText, "sample", "status");
};
```

What am I missing? How do I get the search charm to actually activate my app and display the results page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have search working for a C# project. I created a startup js project and search was working within 2 mins. Here's what I did

Add a search contract,
Click Add New -> Search Contract

by default the js file is called searchResults.js

On your home page or default.html page add a reference to the searchResults.js

Here's what mine looks like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App4</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- App4 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/searchResults.js"></script>
</head>
```

Finally in the app manifest Declarations, select Search for supported Declarations. The properties on the right are empty in my case.

and that's it! 
I put a break point in the onQuerySubmitted function. I run the app, call the search charm (Windows Key + Q) 
start typing text and on pressing enter it should hit the breakpoint!

```
appModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onquerysubmitted = function (args)
{
    nav.navigate(searchPageURI, args); // put breakpoint here
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Syler, thanks for your answer, like you say it should be that simple but I seem to have an issue somewhere. I actually just tried deleting my original searchResult files that were added and started a fresh but still no luck. I don't get any errors when I go control+Q and search, it just does nothing. Any ideas what could be broken?

Comment: Hi slyer, just further clarification. I get my app added to the search list - what I'm looking for is how I bring up the default results page. Do you see that when you search?

Comment: Hi James, have you tried putting a breakpoint in the function for onQuerySubmitted?   you still have to implement the filtering/search logic and display data on your search page.

Comment: Yep, I've done that now. I hadn't actually heard of breakpoints before (I'm new!). So the app does break once I do a search so that is working. What I couldn't do is display a page on submitted the search query.

Comment: Try using navigate instead of nav.navigate.   appModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onquerysubmitted = function (args)
    {        
        navigate(searchPageURI);
    };

Comment: That works, but you still have to implement your search logic.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for that. I struggle understanding some of the documentation at the stage and didn't realise it was that simple. You've been a great help.